# Selection of elements based on data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to select a specific element based on the contents of the data.

Suppose I have a table with two cells, Red & Blue. I have a bunch of data of the form `["Red", "Blue", "Blue", ... ]`

My question is how could I modify the appropriate cell based on the number of matching data. For example, if there were 5 Blue's and 3 Red's, the Blue cell would have a background of #00f at 50% opacity, and the Red would be #f00 at 30% opacity.

So far, I've only seen functionality that modifies all elements in a set (eg. `selectAll("p")`) or even a subsection via filtering.

Is there a way to select specific elements based on the data?

Answer (score 0):

I would use d3 to construct the table if possible: http://jsfiddle.net/ztGE9/2/

```
var data = [["Red","Blue","Blue"], ["Red"], ["Blue"], ["Red", "Blue"], ["Red", "Blue", "Red"], ["Red","Red","Red","Red","Blue"]];

var table = d3.select("#container").append("table"),
    tbody = table.append("tbody");

var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("tr");

var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
    .data(function (row) {
        var tally = {Red:0,Blue:0};
        row.forEach(function(item) {
            tally[item]++;
        });
        return ["rgba(255,0,0,"+ tally["Red"]*0.1 +")",
                "rgba(0,0,255,"+ tally["Blue"]*0.1 +")"];
    })
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .text("foo")
    .style("background-color", function(d) {
        console.log(d);
        return d;
    });
```

If your HTML already has the table encoded in it, you could get the text of each `td` and use regular expressions to tally things -- no need to select things based on their data, per se. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/aKtct/.

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td"),
    forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

forEach.call(tds, function (td) {
    var redMatch = td.textContent.match(/Red/g),
        redCt = redMatch && redMatch.length || 0,
        blueMatch = td.textContent.match(/Blue/g),
        blueCt = blueMatch && blueMatch.length || 0;
    var rgba = redCt ? "rgba(255,0,0," + 0.1 * redCt + ");" :
                       "rgba(0,0,255," + 0.1 * blueCt + ");";
    td.style.cssText += "background-color:" + rgba;
})
```

If you *really* want to select elements based on data, use [custom data attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) and an attribute selector like `$("#td[data-something='RedRedRedBlue']")`.